# Do temporary tables make functions non deterministic in MySQL

Tags: mysql, deterministic

I want to create a stored function in MySQL. I've been granted ALL PRIVILEGES, what I think contains also the required SUPER privilege. And binary logging is enabled.

While creating a function I get the 1419 error:

```
Error Code: 1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

I read through the MySQL manuals and it looks like this binary logging issue should only apply to NOT DETERMINISTIC functions, which change data.
I've created a simple example function which points out my question more clearly:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getIdTest;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION getIdTest( pv_order_nr VARCHAR( 45 ) )
RETURNS INT UNSIGNED

COMMENT 'Gets an order number and returns an ID'
DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA

BEGIN

  DECLARE lv_id INT UNSIGNED;

  -- DOES THIS COMMAND MAKE THE FUNCTION NOT-DETERMINISTIC?
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_log(
      order_nr   VARCHAR(45)
    , message    VARCHAR(255)
    , created_at DATETIME
  );

  -- AND/OR DOES THIS COMMAND MAKE THE FUNCTION NON-DETERMINISTIC?
  INSERT INTO tmp_log
  SET order_nr   = pv_order_nr
    , message    = CONCAT( 'Id read for order ', pv_order_nr, '.')
    , created_at = NOW();

  SELECT so.id_sales_order
  INTO lv_id
  FROM sales_order AS so
  WHERE so.order_nr = pv_order_nr
  LIMIT 1;

  RETURN lv_id;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

As you see my function is declared as DETERMINISTIC.

My question is, does the second statement in the function routine body (CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE) make the function NOT DETERMINISTIC?

If I omit this statement, does the third statement (INSERT INTO --*a temporary table*--) make the function NOT DETERMINISTIC as well?

Thanks for reading this :)

Felix

Comment: I want to have some more advanced logging than the standard db logs

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating a cursor on a temp table - is it safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234029/creating-a-cursor-on-a-temp-table-is-it-safe)