# SQL Server : declare cursor statement cannot recognize the table

Tags: sql-server

In my stored procedure, I created a temp table using *SELECT INTO* statement and when I want to use my temp table in Cursor, it said that '`invalid object name`'

```
DECLARE @sql_temp_table NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql_temp_table = 'SELECT ''PORT_ALM'' AS tbl_a, col_name AS tbl_b, ''A_'' + col_name AS tbl_c INTO #temp_a FROM ' + @lkup_port_logic + ' WHERE ALM_FLG = ''Y''' + CHAR(13) +
                         'UNION' + CHAR(13) +
                         'SELECT ''PORT_FTP'' AS tbl_a, col_name AS tbl_b, ''F_'' + col_name AS tbl_c FROM #temp_a WHERE FTP_FLG = ''Y''' + CHAR(13) +
                         'UNION' + CHAR(13) +
                         'SELECT ''PORT_LCR'' AS tbl_a, col_name AS tbl_b, ''L_'' + col_name AS tbl_c FROM #temp_a WHERE LCR_FLG = ''Y''' + CHAR(13) +
                         ''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql_temp_table

DECLARE @sql_add_col NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql_sel_stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE SECONDCURSOR CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT * FROM #temp_a
```

On running the following statement:

```
DECLARE SECONDCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #temp_a
```

the `#temp_a` is marked as invalid object name

Comment: is it # sign consider as comment in mysql, but i dont know in sql-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234029/creating-a-cursor-on-a-temp-table-is-it-safe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I don't see any INTO clause.

Comment: the INTO clause is in here ''SELECT ''PORT_ALM'' AS tbl_a, col_name AS tbl_b, ''A_'' + col_name AS tbl_c INTO #temp_a FROM ''

Comment: Ugh. Your entire procedure should be thrown away - dynamic sql, sql injection vulnerability and cursors. Are you entering a competition to write the most detestable stored procedure ever? The reason it's not working out is that your dynamic sql isn't executing in the same context as the rest of your query and a parent context cannot access child context objects. That temp table simply doesn't exist in the eyes of the calling code. Learn how to patameterise your dynamic sql and create your temp table outside of the dynamic sql. But really consider throwing this crap away and go a different way

Comment: Would that `UNION` select even run? The first branch of the `UNION` performs a `SELECT ... INTO` to *create* a temp table, the remaining branches want to select *from* that same temp table. Take a step back, abandon what you have here, and explain *what result you want to achieve*, and provide the *inputs* and some sample data.

Comment: Hi Damien, the union select is run if it run as query, but when used stored procedure, the #temp_a is not created

Comment: When I try that (`SELECT * INTO #TE FROM WhatEver UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #TE`), I get `Msg 2770, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The SELECT INTO statement cannot have same source and destination tables.`